# How to set ImageView on a Bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android, view, bitmap, imageview

How can i put an Imageview on a bitmap?
Im working on a campus positioning app for android in java. Here is the problem: i have a campus-map with all rooms and floors. I want to to display a picture (f.e. a library icon) on the map with specific x and y coordinate so the user can see where the library is on the map. when the user zooms in, the library icon should stay on  the room. the icon has to be an ImageView because i need to add a clickListener to start the pathfinding.

I have no idea how to approach this problem.
I tried to put the ImageView on the Bitmap but I dont know if it is even possible.

Comment: `tried to put the ImageView on the Bitmap` ??? What do you have in mind? An ImageView can display a bitmap. Or images.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Glide Library and pass the Bitmap and imageView to it.

use method,

```
Glide.with(this).load(YOUR_BITMAP).into(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW);
```

Following is the link to view details of the library

https://github.com/bumptech/glide